# Windows prompts "activex component can't create object" in vb6

Tags: vb6

I wrote an activex with name "monitor.exe" and another program named "main.exe" .Compiling the main.exe reference the monitor.exe, 
the main exe could run on only computer in where it was implemented ,on other computers,the windows prompts an error message

```
"activex component can't create object".
```

The environment is win7 64bit , the language for development is vb6.

Comment: Did you register the monitor.exe with regsvr32?

Comment: Thanks for your help.But I don't  know how to register the monitor.exe with regsvr32.Could you tell me the detail?

Answer (score 1):

Monitor /registerserver

and

Monitor /unregisterserver

Or

Just Double Click the Monitor.exe in explorer.

Either way this should do it.